# Linux ls shows files with yellow background color

Tags: linux, file, colors, ls

what does this yellow (orange on Ubuntu) background color mean in ls?

[image]

```
neoexpert@sonderbyte:/srv/thing$ ls -l
total 32
drwxrwsr-x 2 root developers 4096 Aug 25 12:30 branches
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root developers   66 Aug 25 12:30 config
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root developers   73 Aug 25 12:30 description
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root developers   23 Aug 25 12:30 HEAD
drwxrwsr-x 2 root developers 4096 Aug 25 14:00 hooks
drwxrwsr-x 2 root developers 4096 Aug 25 12:30 info
drwxrwsr-x 4 root developers 4096 Aug 25 12:30 objects
drwxrwsr-x 4 root developers 4096 Aug 25 12:30 refs
neoexpert@sonderbyte:/srv/thing$
```

Comment: Try `/bin/ls -F` then `ls -lF`.

Comment: I did "chmod -R g+s thing/" before they appeared with that background color

Comment: That was wrong, notably the `-R`

Comment: It is for the git repositority, when an user creates a file then it will have the group "developers" and not default group from that user. the directory should be writebale for the group developers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try `ls -l` to find out (this is faster than asking here).

Read [ls(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ls.1.html) and look at your `LS_COLORS` environment variable using `echo $LS_COLORS`

(looks like you have suspicious [sticky bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sticky_bit) on plain files; see also [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/79395/50557); try also [stat(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/stat.1.html) on the strange files....)

Don't use sticky bit on files (only on directories).

BTW, I suspect that setting sticky bit for `git` is a mistake.

Comment: No they are not. here is an entry from ls -l: -rw-rwSr-- 1 root developers   66 Aug 25 12:30 config

Comment: That should go into your question. The `S` bit is suspicious.

Comment: Thank you. the sticky bit was the reason: I did then "sudo find . -type f -print0 | sudo xargs -0 chmod g-s"

Comment: Please edit your question for future reference, by giving there (as *text* i.e. with four spaces at start of line) the `ls` command you did

Comment: What is the common approach than to make a directory writeable for a specific group? when I do for example "mkdir test" then, the directory will have "neoexpert" (my default group) as group

Comment: I think you should ask the question on how to use `git`  in such a way that the group is nice.